# Run Git commands and parse log History from java Program

Tags: java, xml, git, repository, svnkit

I am trying to write a java program that should analyse at runtime Log history information
of any `<<input>>` given Git Repository (grab authors, date, path of files, modifications and actions on these files such as Modify Add Delete etc...). But I'm figuring out one main issue :

**1:** Is it possible to directly execute git commands from my java code maybe using some libraries that will avoid me first need to Clone the repository and execute a git log...??
(***a kind of svnKit library for GIT ?*** )

Note the main goal at the end of this process is to have these Log history informations in a Xml output file
- Any library to achieve this ?
- Or i would need to parse and build on my own the xml file..?

Answer (score 2):

You can use JGit; however, JGit will still need to be told to clone the repository.

---

If you just want the history of a repository as a single file, there is a standard for this, and it's called the git-fast-import file format. You can produce a git-fast-import file for a git repository using the command `git fast-export`.

Comment: i'm trying to figure out how to call this git fast-export. should i first have to install JGit ? or i can call it without ? can you please provide me a short example assuming for example that i whant to fetch info from https://code.google.com/p/gitblit/    Thanks in advance..

Comment: `git fast-export` is part of the Git suite; it is nothing to do with JGit. So yes, you can call it without it. To do it in Java you can use `ProcessBuilder`; alternatively, to do it in a bash shell script you can just write `git clone` *repository-url* `; cd` *repository* `; git fast-export`